# jQuery trigger() on page load does not work

Tags: jquery

I trying to get jQuery to click a link when a page loads, and I 'm doing it like below. But nothing seems to work. I need things just the way they are, since I also call the `function` with the same link later. Any idea where I seem to be doing things wrong, and how to do this right?

The function works fine If I manually click the link after the page loads.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Test trigger</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/site/scripts/jQueryCore.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".link").trigger('click');

    $('.link').click(function () {
        console.log('I was clicked');
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">
        <span class="link">Click Me</span>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to trigger the event after the handler is registered to the target element. When an event is triggered on an element only those handlers which are already registered in it will be invoked

```
$('.link').click(function () {
    console.log('I was clicked');
});
$(".link").trigger('click');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/u6vZp/)

Comment: Thanks for this. I just spent hours trying to figure it out myself.